# Spacing issue with conditional compilation directives with VS Community 2015

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2015, resharper

I have recently tried using Visual Studio 2015 Community edition as my IDE for editing Unity C# scripts. I should note that I am also using ReSharper.

When I am using Unity conditional-compilation directives the code formats to include two lines before the initial if directive. Due to me formatting on save, every time I save I am inserting two more lines before this directive.

For example if I have

```
void SomeMethod() {
  #if UNITY_WEBPLAYER
    ...
  #endif
}
```

Every time I reformat the document two newlines are added abouve the #if. I have scoured the C# code formatting menu as well as the code formatting section under the ReSharper menu, and I am not seeing an entry for conditional compilation directives. Is there some option that these are merged with that I am not noticing, or am I just blind?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is not happening for me. What command are you using to format the code?

Comment: Yeah, this is not happening for me using the VS Format Document command or the Resharper format tool.